# The R code for left join, working with Dates that are matching and others not matching

Tags: r

```r
dfy<-tibble(ttc= c("830592962A","701134213K","620001491E","500542890M","400259766M","800136692H","701229741E"),
            CaseDate1=c("01/04/2019","01/04/2019","02/04/2019","02/04/2019","02/04/2019","02/04/2019","03/04/2019"),
            Theatre=c("RIE_TH_06","RIE_TH_06","RIE_TH_08","RIE_TH_08","RIE_TH_06","RIE_TH_06","RIE_TH_08"))

dss<-tibble(ttc=c("400259766M","800136692H","701229741E","830592962A","701134213K","620001491E","500542890M"),
            D1=c("NA","01/04/2019","NA","01/04/2019","01/04/2019","02/04/2019","NA"),
            D2=c("02/04/2019","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","02/04/2019"),
            D3=c("NA","NA","04/04/2019","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
            C5=c("APPLE","ORANGE","PINE","MANGO","CHERRY","SUGAR","GREEN"))
```

1. Firstly i want to left joint the file based on exact matches of

```r
dfy(ttc&CaseDate1)

dss(ttc& coalesce(D1,D2,D3))
```

2. Secondly, where there is no exact matches i want to use (a day before or a day after in `dss(ttc& coalesce(D1,D2,D3))`
3. `dfy( 701229741E& 03/04/2019)` will mathc into `dss(701229741E&04/04/201)` a day after or  a day before

I have used the following code and has joined only the matching ttc& dates

```
dfy %>% 
  left_join(dss %>% mutate(x = coalesce(D1, D2, D3)), by = c("ttc", "CaseDate1" = "x")) %>% 
  select(ttc, CaseDate1, Theatre, C5)
```

Comment: dfy and dss are the 2 data frames ..dplyr

Comment: What's UHPI? I think you should transform the `dss` dataframe to longer format before the join, have you done that? What have you done so far?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: What is the expected output for the given data?

Comment: 701229741E& 03/04/2019 from dfy doesnt match with 701229741E&04/04/201 from dss because the dates are not the same. I want to have a code which then  matches if dates are different e.g 701229741E& 03/04/2019 can match to 701229741E&02/04/201  or 701229741E&03/04/201 ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce is not working as intended because in the data "NA" is a string, not a missing data. I fixed that with

```
for (c in c('D1', 'D2', 'D3')) {
  dss[c][dss[c] == 'NA'] = NA
}
```

Now your same code returns

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  ttc        CaseDate1  Theatre   C5    
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr> 
1 830592962A 01/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 MANGO 
2 701134213K 01/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 CHERRY
3 620001491E 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 SUGAR 
4 500542890M 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 GREEN 
5 400259766M 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 APPLE 
6 800136692H 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 NA    
7 701229741E 03/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 NA
```

For the missing date, my suggestion would  be use a `full_join` instead of `left_join`, and use the `fill` function in a grouped dataframe:

```
dfy %>% 
  full_join(dss %>% mutate(x = coalesce(D1, D2, D3)), by = c("ttc", "CaseDate1" = "x")) %>% 
  select(ttc, CaseDate1, Theatre, C5) %>%
  group_by(ttc) %>%
  arrange(desc(CaseDate1)) %>%
  fill(C5) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Theatre)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(CaseDate1)
```

outputs

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  ttc        CaseDate1  Theatre   C5    
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr> 
1 830592962A 01/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 MANGO 
2 701134213K 01/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 CHERRY
3 620001491E 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 SUGAR 
4 500542890M 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 GREEN 
5 400259766M 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 APPLE 
6 800136692H 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 NA    
7 701229741E 03/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 PINE
```

`filter(!is.na(Theatre))` here is dropping whatever was not in the `dfy` (the "left" dataframe).

If you want to fill in both directions, you can add the `.direction` argument to the `fill` function.

```
dfy %>% 
  full_join(dss %>% mutate(x = coalesce(D1, D2, D3)), by = c("ttc", "CaseDate1" = "x")) %>% 
  select(ttc, CaseDate1, Theatre, C5) %>%
  group_by(ttc) %>%
  arrange(desc(CaseDate1)) %>%
  fill(C5, .direction='updown') %>%
  filter(!is.na(Theatre)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(CaseDate1)
```

and outputs

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  ttc        CaseDate1  Theatre   C5    
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr> 
1 830592962A 01/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 MANGO 
2 701134213K 01/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 CHERRY
3 620001491E 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 SUGAR 
4 500542890M 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 GREEN 
5 400259766M 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 APPLE 
6 800136692H 02/04/2019 RIE_TH_06 ORANGE
7 701229741E 03/04/2019 RIE_TH_08 PINE
```

It is not clear to me that this is your intended output, but I hope it helps you in the right direction.